# How to parse this JSON using a JSON Condition Expression?

Tags: arrays, json, expression, jsonpath, jsonparser

I have this sample JSON and want to write a parser to get the desired output.

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
  "prizes": [
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "physics",
      "overallMotivation": "\"for groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\"",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "960",
          "firstname": "Arthur",
          "surname": "Ashkin",
          "motivation": "\"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "961",
          "firstname": "Gérard",
          "surname": "Mourou",
          "motivation": "\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
          "share": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "962",
          "firstname": "Donna",
          "surname": "Strickland",
          "motivation": "\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"",
          "share": "4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "chemistry",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "963",
          "firstname": "Frances H.",
          "surname": "Arnold",
          "motivation": "\"for the directed evolution of enzymes\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "964",
          "firstname": "George P.",
          "surname": "Smith",
          "motivation": "\"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies\"",
          "share": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "965",
          "firstname": "Sir Gregory P.",
          "surname": "Winter",
          "motivation": "\"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies\"",
          "share": "4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "medicine",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "958",
          "firstname": "James P.",
          "surname": "Allison",
          "motivation": "\"for their discovery of cancer therapy by inhibition of negative immune regulation\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "959",
          "firstname": "Tasuku",
          "surname": "Honjo",
          "motivation": "\"for their discovery of cancer therapy by inhibition of negative immune regulation\"",
          "share": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "peace",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "966",
          "firstname": "Denis",
          "surname": "Mukwege",
          "motivation": "\"for their efforts to end the use of sexual violence as a weapon of war and armed conflict\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "967",
          "firstname": "Nadia",
          "surname": "Murad",
          "motivation": "\"for their efforts to end the use of sexual violence as a weapon of war and armed conflict\"",
          "share": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2018",
      "category": "economics",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "968",
          "firstname": "William D.",
          "surname": "Nordhaus",
          "motivation": "\"for integrating climate change into long-run macroeconomic analysis\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "969",
          "firstname": "Paul M.",
          "surname": "Romer",
          "motivation": "\"for integrating technological innovations into long-run macroeconomic analysis\"",
          "share": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2014",
      "category": "peace",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "913",
          "firstname": "Kailash",
          "surname": "Satyarthi",
          "motivation": "\"for their struggle against the suppression of children and young people and for the right of all children to education\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "914",
          "firstname": "Malala",
          "surname": "Yousafzai",
          "motivation": "\"for their struggle against the suppression of children and young people and for the right of all children to education\"",
          "share": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2017",
      "category": "physics",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "941",
          "firstname": "Rainer",
          "surname": "Weiss",
          "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
          "share": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "942",
          "firstname": "Barry C.",
          "surname": "Barish",
          "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
          "share": "4"
        },
        {
          "id": "943",
          "firstname": "Kip S.",
          "surname": "Thorne",
          "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
          "share": "4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2017",
      "category": "chemistry",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "944",
          "firstname": "Jacques",
          "surname": "Dubochet",
          "motivation": "\"for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution\"",
          "share": "3"
        },
        {
          "id": "945",
          "firstname": "Joachim",
          "surname": "Frank",
          "motivation": "\"for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution\"",
          "share": "3"
        },
        {
          "id": "946",
          "firstname": "Richard",
          "surname": "Henderson",
          "motivation": "\"for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution\"",
          "share": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "year": "2017",
      "category": "medicine",
      "laureates": [
        {
          "id": "938",
          "firstname": "Jeffrey C.",
          "surname": "Hall",
          "motivation": "\"for their discoveries of molecular mechanisms controlling the circadian rhythm\"",
          "share": "3"
        },
        {
          "id": "939",
          "firstname": "Michael",
          "surname": "Rosbash",
          "motivation": "\"for their discoveries of molecular mechanisms controlling the circadian rhythm\"",
          "share": "3"
        },
        {
          "id": "940",
          "firstname": "Michael W.",
          "surname": "Young",
          "motivation": "\"for their discoveries of molecular mechanisms controlling the circadian rhythm\"",
          "share": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "914",
    "firstname": "Malala",
    "surname": "Yousafzai",
    "motivation": "\"for their struggle against the suppression of children and young people and for the right of all children to education\"",
    "share": "2"
  }
]
```

So if I write `$.prizes[5].laureates[1]` it gives the required answer. But I want to get the same output using conditional logic because the order of entries are not guaranteed.

So I tried like this `$.prizes[?(@.laureates[?(@.firstname == "Malala")])]` and it's not working. My question is around using nested conditional logic inside arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.prizes[*].laureates[*]` would give all of the laureates items, and then you can apply filter on it :

```
$.prizes[*].laureates[?(@.firstname == "Malala")]
```

or shorter with deep scan :

```
$..[?(@.firstname == "Malala")]
```

Comment: Thank You for helping me. I figured it out myself. I have posted the same down below

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
$.*.*.*[?(@.firstname == "Malala")]
```